# how to make a unique string using php and mysql records before inserting it, and maintain if generated once then do not generate

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating invoice number using php mysql.

My unique id will be on the form: "vend/year/id/order_no", where a

vend is string

year is current year

id is vendor_id

order no is : count order by vender_id from other table(order table) , incremented by one.

My issue occurs, when user opens the "order" web page, then i have to show this generated id before the user fill the form and submit the form, so id has to be generated first, yet not inserted.

Now let user open web page in two tab, then according to logic both web page will show same id.
but user tries to submit both form, then first submission will be accepted as per unique constraints , second query will fail,
but i don't want that,
and b/c it is vendor base work, 100k users will be accessing that table so i can't create a lock on table.
and neither i can stop him opening webpage in two tab.
What is the best way to maintain this.

Comment: Personally at time of submission I would check the databse again for the id and increment it if it already exists.  This way no matter how many screens you have open it will always insert correctly.  If the ID needs to be known by the agent or customer if you change the id for some reason make the app fire up a prompt letting them know the new ID.

Comment: as i have written in last para ,i have simply created a string but problem occurs when user open multiple tabs seeing same invoice id.and try to submit a complex form, but one is submitted and other are not. or when more user having access and working simultaneously

Comment: @SubstanceD by this user is saying that i was getting that id for my reference and id has changed for that invoice. so it is not possible in app.

Comment: Why can't you show the generated string after the form has been submitted? It will be 100% accurate and you won't need to add locks.

Comment: Why the order ID has to exist before inserting it? Can't you do like everyone else and create the ID at submit time and then inform it to the user (in case its actually necessary)?

Comment: I still think its very feasable to deal with this after the form has been submitted.  how i do it is create a variable with id it it and use a while loop to check for the id in the db.  if its found increment the id.  the while loop will do selects until it gets to an id thats not been used.  You can then do your insert with that new id.

Comment: yes i know but it is a neeed of application

Comment: I think you should use "Insert ... on Duplicate key " statement to catch case order id already exist, you can count orderid, get max order id then update again.
After that, you should notice to user about new order id.
Another way, store order id in file, on each order page open, get id in file, then increase 1, save to file. So, order id never duplicate.

Comment: I was thinking, solution might be to store generated id in other table, having some status, and match newly generate id from this table, so user will always get new_id, but basic issue is it is very lengthy and count will be the issue

Comment: It's an unnecessary overhead. You don't have to tell the customer what it's unique id is until after you've made the insert, if you do that then you will end up having missing fields because some customers will not finish their request once you've given them the unique id, causing you a lot of trouble perhaps and inconsistent database information. Just: Submit -> Insert -> Show id and the wonderful "success" message. Instead of: Show id -> Submit -> Insert -> Show the wonderful "success"... it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two main approaches:

1) Reserve the Unique ID when the invoice form is opened, this can be done by saving the last reserved id somewhere in the database. One advantage is that each open window will have a unique ID, however any invoices not submited become "wasted" IDs. You could have a mechanism to use these "wasted" IDs or just ignore them.

2) On save check for ID validity and either update automatically or ask user for permission. This could possibly get annoying.

I prefer approach 1)

Answer (score 0):

Give the user a notice/warning:

"The given ordernumber 123 is already being used, do you want use ordernumber 124 instead?"

or skip the question and just tell the user that number 124 was used instead

Comment: but in a professional app, if id has generated once, then how can i show that it is already used  while it was generated for him.